# Prove or disprove : In a topological space $(X,\tau)$ if every compact subsets $K\subset X$ are closed then $(X, \tau) $ is hausdorff.

Tags: general-topology, compactness, examples-counterexamples, separation-axioms

$(X, \tau) $ be a topological space.

$K\subset X$ is compact.

I can prove if $X$ is hausdorff space then $K\subset X$ is closed.

I know that the proof strongly requires the $T_2$- property of $X$.

But if $X$ is not hausdorff then a compact subset is not necessarily closed.

The simplest example, $X=\{0, 1\}$ and $\tau=\{\emptyset ,\{0\},X\}$

Then, $K=\{0\}\subset X$ is compact but not closed.

**My question** : In a topological space $(X,\tau)$ if every compact subsets $K\subset X$ are closed then $(X, \tau) $ is hausdorff.

This may be a simplest question, I mean there may be some trivial example but i am not able to solve it.

Comment: A space where all compact subsets are closed is called a KC-space. Such a space is always $T_1$ (as singletons are always compact, thus closed), but need not be Hausdorff. See Santos' answer, which is the standard example (even mentioned in the paper where the KC property was first defined).

Comment: @Henno Brandsma Can you give me an example other than Cocountable topology on uncountable set?

Comment: I believe the Aleksandrov extension of $\Bbb Q$ is another.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Let $X$ be an infinite uncountable set, endowed the cocountable topology $\tau$. Then $(X,\tau)$ is not Hausdorff, but the only compact subsets of $X$ are the finite ones, which are closed subsets.

Comment: If $A$ is an infinite subset of $X$, then let $B\subset A$ be a countable set and, for each $x \in B$ let be $U_x = (X\setminus B) \cup \{x\}$, which is open because $B$ is countable. Then $A\subset\bigcup _{x\in B} U_x$, but $\{U_x\mid x\in B\}$ has no finite subcover. Thus, $A$ is not compact.

Comment: Or say that if $B$ is infinite, pick a countably infinite  subset $N \subseteq B$. Then $N$ is closed and discrete as a subspace. So $B$ is not even countably compact, let alone compact.