# What are some examples of non Hausdorff spaces where $\mathcal{F}=Y^X$

Tags: general-topology, continuity, soft-question, compactness, separation-axioms

$(X, \tau_X), (Y, \tau_Y) $ be two topological spaces and $|\tau_Y |\ge 3$

Consider $\mathcal{F}=\{f\in Y^X : f^{-1}(A)\subset X \text{ compact}\space,\forall A\subset Y \text{ closed}\}$

> Can we classify all topological spaces $(X,\tau_X)$ such that
> $\mathcal{F}=Y^X$ ?

---

If $\tau_X$ induced a Hausdorff topology on $X$ , then every $K\subset X$ compact implies $K\subset X$ is closed.

Then $ \mathcal{F}=C(X, Y) $ and given $|\tau_Y|\ge 3$ implies $(X, \tau_X) $ is the discrete space ( see the [proof](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4450473/977780) ) and $C(X,Y) \subset \mathcal{F} $ implies every closed subsets of $X$ is compact.Hence $X $ is a finite set.

---

There are non Hausdorff spaces $(X,\tau_X)$ where all compact  subsets are closed. ( [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4357310/977780) are some examples).

Then $\mathcal{F}=C(X, Y) $

Now from [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4450473/977780) , we can conclude that $(X, \tau_X) $ is the discrete space.

$C(X, Y) \subset \mathcal{F}$ implies every closed subsets of $X$ are compact.

**Does there exists any non Hausdorff spaces where each compact subsets are closed and closed subsets are compact ?**

If such set exists then it creates a weird situation here ! This topological space doesn't satisfy $\mathcal{F}=Y^X$.

> What are some examples of non Hausdorff spaces where $\mathcal{F}=Y^X$ ?

Here $Y^X$ denotes thr class of all functions from $X$ to $Y$.

Comment: I don't know if I'm missing something but I think your first argument is wrong. It is true that if $(X, \tau_X)$ is Hausdorff then $\mathcal{F}=C(X, Y)$, but you cannot conclude that $(X, \tau_X)$ is discrete. In the link you provide what it is proven is that if $C(X,Y)=Y^X$ then $X$ is discrete. But you don't have that in this case. Just consider $X=Y=\mathbb{R}$ with the standard topology.

Comment: I assume $C(X, Y) =Y^X$, then I am trying to find the nature of the topological space .

Comment: Oh, sorry! That's true :)

Comment: You should edit your question to explain that $Y^X$ denotes the set of all functions $f : X \to Y$. Frequently $Y^X$ is used to denote the set of all **continuous functions**.

Comment: A necessary condition for $\mathcal F = Y^X$ is that $X$ is compact. In fact, pick any $f\in Y^X$ and conclude that $X = f^{-1}(Y)$ is compact. And why does $C(X, Y) \subset \mathcal{F}$ imply that every closed subsets of $X$ is compact? Not all compact subsets may be preimages of closed subsets under a continuous map. But since $X$ has to be compact, it is true without any additional assumption that all closed subsets are compact.